# How can I highlight different keywords according to a suffix?

Tags: font-lock, syntax-highlighting

I want to highlight `foo` in `foo::` without highlighting `foo::<bar>`, using `font-lock-keywords`. This is the result I want:

[image: correct higlighting]

Initially I tried this:

```
(defvar example-font-lock-keywords
  `((,(rx (group (1+ word)) "::" (not (any "<"))) 1 font-lock-type-face)))

(define-derived-mode example-mode prog-mode "Example"
  (setq-local font-lock-defaults '(example-font-lock-keywords)))
```

But that gave the following:

[image: bad trailing character]

Instead I tried two separate keywords:

```
(defvar example-font-lock-keywords
  `((,(rx (group (1+ word)) "::") 1 font-lock-type-face)
    ;; This is ignored if I use `default', but other faces work!
    (,(rx (group (1+ word)) "::<") 1 font-lock-variable-name-face t)))

(define-derived-mode example-mode prog-mode "Example"
  (setq-local font-lock-defaults '(example-font-lock-keywords)))
```

The second pattern is used if I specify `font-lock-variable-name-face`, but if I use `default`, the whole pattern is ignored!

Comment: Question: In the example given the colons after module1 are not highlighted, whilst description says foo:: - including colons. Understand it's about foo (colon) not followed by foo (colon) <bar> - where colons never get highlight.

Comment: I don't want to highlight the colons. I've clarified the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your regular expression eats the character behind the second colon and the next search starts behind that character. That is why the first letter of `module2` is not highlighted.

You may only look at the character behind the second colon but you may not include it into the regular expression.

**Basis** for a working version:

```lisp
(defvar example-font-lock-keywords
  `((example-font-lock-matcher 1 font-lock-type-face)))

(defun example-font-lock-matcher (limit)
  "Matcher matching \"keyword::\" but only if we are not looking at < afterwards."
  (let (match)
    (while (and (setq match (re-search-forward "\\_<\\(\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\)::" limit t))
        (eq (char-after) ?<)))
    match))

(define-derived-mode example-mode prog-mode "Example"
  (setq-local font-lock-defaults '(example-font-lock-keywords)))
```

I think that solves your question, but you have still work to do. For an instance you should consider whether there may be some whitespace in between the colon and the `<`.

If you actually always want to highlight the first keyword in the case that the two colons are followed by a further keyword the following version would be even more appropriate:

```lisp
(defvar example-font-lock-keywords
  `(("\\_<\\(\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\)::[[:space:]]*\\_<" 1 font-lock-type-face)))

(define-derived-mode example-mode prog-mode "Example"
  (setq-local font-lock-defaults '(example-font-lock-keywords)))
```

---

Allow me one further remark. It would be nice if you would not only post a picture of the text to be highlighted but also the text itself. This would ease the reconstruction of the problem for the people who want to help you.
I do so here for other potential helpers:

```
use module1::function;
use module1::module2::function;

foo::<bar>
```

Comment: Thanks, that almost works. There's never any whitespace before the `<`. However, your matcher solution also highlights the `::`, which isn't what I want. (P.s. sorry for not pasting the sample text!)

Comment: Edited to fix the issue mentioned.